# some regions can't resolve my domain by using ns of aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

**step1: I've just registered a new domain from Route53, the default Name Server like this:**

[image]

**step2: then I also used Hosted Zones to Manage My domain and add some A records. like this:**

[image]

**I followed some tips to make these two place have the same NS,my questions are:**

1. I made the Hosted Zones Name server identical to those in Registered Domain(now all NS are those in first picture), but it didn't work.

   **error (from online resolving website) something like**:
   *Response: Unknown (refused at ns-631.awsdns-14.net).
   Sorry, I could not continue.*

   **nslookup command returned something like:**
   "server can't find www.domain.com: NXDOMAIN"
2. I made Registered Domain NS identical to those in the Hosted Zones(now all NS are those in second picture)
   this time it seemed to work,see pictures:

   [image]
   [image]

**however it brought another question:**

I can't access my domain in my network.My personal computer's DNS is 192.168.1.254 (from my router).If I change it to 8.8.8.8. it worked. I'm not sure if others could resolve my domain or not. And I also can't force them to change their DNS server

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how long since you did step (2)? (which is correct, BTW). Note 192.168.1.* is unrouteable, so it's a "local" DNS server. It may be your router or modem.

Comment: @tedder42  I'd done step(2) more than 12 hours.  Yes,192.168.1.* is my local DNS,but it couldn't resolve my domain. but 8.8.8.8 worked.

Comment: if it's your local DNS, it points to somewhere "upstream", like your ISP or opendns. There are also extreme cases where it takes longer than 12 hours (TTL is a suggestion)- I wouldn't be 100% confident until 120 hours have passed.

Comment: @tedder42    Thank you !  I'd like to wait for 120 hours to see the result. :)